# Getting duplicate entries in treeView and Extra Space in listView Item image

Tags: vb.net

I am making a test program to let the user select a folder from a tree view which will show the drives and folders (when expanded) and the files that are present in the selected folder will be displayed in the listview.
The problem i am facing with the listview is that, there is a extra space added before the file icon of every file.
And i am also getting duplicate folder entries when expanded in the treeview.

the icon size of imageListListView is 24x24

```
Public Class FolderTreeStructure
Private Sub FolderTreeStructre_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'add drive list in treeview
    Dim drives() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives()
    For Each drive In drives
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(drive)
    Next

    'add folder present in each drives
    Dim folders() As String
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To TreeView1.Nodes.Count - 1
        Try
            folders = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(TreeView1.Nodes.Item(i).Text)
            For Each folder In folders
                TreeView1.Nodes.Item(i).Nodes.Add(folder)
                TreeView1.Nodes.Item(i).Nodes.Item(j).ImageIndex = 1
                j += 1
            Next
            j = 0
        Catch
            Continue For
        End Try
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_AfterExpand(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterExpand
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Dim folders() As String
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    TreeView1.BeginUpdate()

    For i As Integer = 0 To e.Node.Nodes.Count - 1
        Try
            folders = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(e.Node.Nodes.Item(i).Text)
            For Each folder In folders
                e.Node.Nodes.Item(i).Nodes.Add(folder)
                e.Node.Nodes.Item(i).Nodes.Item(j).ImageIndex = 1
                j += 1
            Next
            j = 0
        Catch
            Continue For
        End Try
    Next
    TreeView1.EndUpdate()
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    addFolderItems(e.Node.Text)
End Sub

Public Sub addFolderItems(ByVal path As String)
    Try
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(path)
        Dim fileCount As Integer = files.Length
        Dim fileInfo As IO.FileInfo
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim Items = ListView1.Items

        'different file sizes
        Dim fileSize As Long
        Dim kb As Double
        Dim mb As Double
        Dim gb As Double

        'for extracting file type description
        Dim Clskey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot
        Dim ExtKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
        Dim Appkey2 As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
        Dim AppDesc As String

        'to hold file icon
        Dim iconForFile As Icon = SystemIcons.WinLogo
        ListView1.BeginUpdate()

        For Each file In files
            Try
                fileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(file)
                'adds item number
                Items.Add(Items.Count + 1)
                'adds file name
                Items.Item(i).SubItems.Add(fileInfo.Name)
                ' Check to see if the image collection contains an image
                ' for this extension, using the extension as a key.
                If Not (ImageListListView.Images.ContainsKey(fileInfo.Extension)) Then
                    ' If not, add the image to the image list.
                    iconForFile = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileInfo.FullName)
                    ImageListListView.Images.Add(fileInfo.Extension, iconForFile)
                End If

                Items.Item(i).ImageKey = fileInfo.Extension
                'adds file size
                fileSize = fileInfo.Length
                If fileSize > 1024 Then
                    kb = fileSize / 1024
                    If kb > 1024 Then
                        mb = kb / 1024
                        If mb > 1024 Then
                            gb = mb / 1024
                            Items.Item(i).SubItems.Add(Format(gb, "0.00") & " GB")
                        Else
                            Items.Item(i).SubItems.Add(Format(mb, "0.00") & " MB")
                        End If
                    Else
                        Items.Item(i).SubItems.Add(Format(kb, "0.00") & " KB")
                    End If
                Else
                    Items.Item(i).SubItems.Add(fileSize.ToString & " bytes")
                End If
                'adds file extension without .
                If fileInfo.Extension.Length > 0 Then
                    Items.Item(i).SubItems.Add(fileInfo.Extension.Substring(1))
                Else
                    Items.Item(i).SubItems.Add(fileInfo.Extension)
                End If
                'adds date modified
                Items.Item(i).SubItems.Add(fileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString)
                'extract file type description from registry
                ExtKey = Clskey.OpenSubKey(fileInfo.Extension, False)
                If ExtKey IsNot Nothing Then 'Occurs nullreff when extension not found
                    AppDesc = ExtKey.GetValue("", "")
                    Appkey2 = Clskey.OpenSubKey(AppDesc)
                    Items.Item(i).SubItems.Add(Appkey2.GetValue("", ""))
                End If
                i += 1
            Catch
                Continue For
            End Try
        Next
        ListView1.EndUpdate()
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox(e.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Link for image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtxiY.png

Comment: Have you debugged, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through the code?  If not, do that now. As soon as the state of the application doesn't match your expectation, you've found an issue and you can investigate further. At the very least you can provide us with more relevant information and remove code that isn't relevant.

Comment: Ok for that, but what about the extra spaces that is added before each items[file icon] in the list? Can you please help me in that?